# tensorflow c++ SetDefaultDevice in multi-gpu mode

Tags: c++, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I wanted to load the same graph on multiple GPUs for inference, however I am unable to associate a graph with a device using the graph::SetDefaultDevice.  The problem occurs not in SetDefaultDevice  but later when creating a session with the graph. Here is a simple example extracted from example_trainer.cc of tensorflow

```
#include <tensorflow/core/platform/env.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/graph/default_device.h"

int main() {
  using namespace tensorflow;
  using namespace tensorflow::ops;
  Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
  auto A = Const(root, { {3.f, 2.f}, {-1.f, 0.f} }); 
  auto b = Const(root, { {3.f, 5.f} }); 
  auto v = MatMul(root.WithOpName("v"), A, b, MatMul::TransposeB(true));

  GraphDef def;
  TF_CHECK_OK(root.ToGraphDef(&def));

  graph::SetDefaultDevice(false ? "/device:GPU:0" : "/cpu:0", &def);
  /*
  for (auto &node: *def.mutable_node()) {
        node.set_device("/cpu:0");
        std::cout << node.name() << " = '" << node.device() <<"'"<< std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "=======================\n";
  */
  SessionOptions options;
  std::unique_ptr<Session> session(NewSession(options));
  TF_CHECK_OK(session->Create(def));
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when running

```
2018-09-06 18:18:13.853316: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-09-06 18:18:13.856079: F /home/daniel/tensorflow_cc/example/example.cpp:27] Non-OK-status: session->Create(def) status: Not found: No attr named '/cpu:0' in NodeDef:
     [[Node: Const = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [2,2] values: [3 2][-1]...>, _device="/cpu:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Const = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [2,2] values: [3 2][-1]...>, _device="/cpu:0"]()]]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I remove the SetDefault Device call it works perfectly. I have tried to do this on a machine with GPU as well and it didn't work.

I know the problem is not with SetDefaultDevice because manually setting the device of each node ends up with the same problem when creating the session.

```
Const = '/cpu:0'
Const_1 = '/cpu:0'
v = '/cpu:0'
=======================
2018-09-06 18:15:05.966337: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-09-06 18:15:05.969048: F /home/daniel/tensorflow_cc/example/example.cpp:26] Non-OK-status: session->Create(def) status: Not found: No attr named '/cpu:0' in NodeDef:
     [[Node: Const = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [2,2] values: [3 2][-1]...>, _device="/cpu:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Const = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [2,2] values: [3 2][-1]...>, _device="/cpu:0"]()]]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue only with monolithic builds (--config=monolithic) i.e. when build libtensorflow_cc.so. I am not sure but it maybe related to

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5379
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16291